# $\int_X^{2X}\lvert f-g\rvert^2=O(X)$ then $\lvert f-g\rvert=O(1)$

Tags: integration, asymptotics

> How can you conclude that if $\int_X^{2X}\lvert f-g\rvert^2=O(X)$ then $\lvert f-g\rvert=O(1)$ for $X\le x\le 2X$ and $X\in\mathbb R$ and large enough.

Does this follow from Cauchy-Schwartz ?

Then the conclusion is automatically valid if we drop the square ?

Comment: This cannot be true in general. One can have $|f-g|$ arbitrary large on a very tiny interval in $[X,2X]$ and still having the integral be $O(X)$.

Comment: @Winther OK I'll edit it, I'm interested in the approximation when $X$ tends to infinity so definitely for $X>1$

Comment: What $X$ is does not really matter that much. The point is that the value of an integral is insensitive to very tall spikes in the integrand as long as they are thin enough. Thus just knowing the value of the integral (a "global" property) does not tell you anything about the individual function values (a "local" property). The converse does hold though: if $f = O(1)$ then $\int_x^{2x} f = O(x)$.